# framework for queuing jobs with webservices

Tags: queue, jms, apache-camel, spring-integration

I'm looking an implementing a web service ( let's call it A) in Java that accepts job requests and then sends these requests to another web service (3rd party service Let's call it B). Nothing complex here. Responses from B to A are synchronous ( returns job id) and then when the job finishes B sends an asynchronous message to A notifying it that the job has finished ( jobs to B can take X time). B can only accept 20 jobs at a time however A should be able to accept as many jobs as possible from multiple clients. So A needs a queing system to only ever send B no more that 20 jobs. When B finishes a job and notifies A, then A can send another job to B.

I could save jobs coming into A in a database with state NEW and then have a process running every 5 min, collects NEW jobs and if <20 jobs processing by B send job. Jobs processing by B would have status PROCESSING and then when B sends job finish to A it sets status to DONE. And just

Can I do this with JMS or a routing engine like Camel or if anyone can provide another framework to help. I haven't been able to find anything that maintains a queue and only ever sends a max of X jobs. The A queue could have hundreds of jobs waiting to be processed but only ever sends another job to B when it finishes another job.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your task is so specific I'm not sure that there is somewhere 'out of the box' solution in any framework.

You are right: the queue is for you. I'm not sure that concurrent consumers is OK in this case, as you need to have 'barrier'.

As the 'barrier' solution I sugggest to have some `AtomicInteger`, when you send the job increment it and send the value to some component which **stop** your consumer, if the 'barrier' is on limit.

When the job is complete you decrement that `AtomicInteger` and **start** the consumer, if 'barrier' less then limit.

Not sure, if Camel allows start/stop endpoints, but Spring Integration relies here on `Lifecycle` of messaging endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need persistence of the jobs that have not been submitted for processing yet, I think all you need is two [blocking queues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

1. Incoming job queue ("large" capacity)
2. jobs pending completion queue (max capacity of 20)

Your web-threads fill the "incoming job queue" with new jobs. A single worker thread takes jobs from that queue one at a time. Then tries to put a token element into the "jobs pending completion queue". If there are less than 20 entries in that queue it will succeed immediately and subsequently submits the job to your service B.

A thread that receives the asynchronous call-back from B will then remove the token elements from the "jobs pending completion queue".
If there are already 20 entries in the queue, the thread trying to submit a new job gets blocked until a callback thread removes a token element.

Comment: Persistence may be required to view processed jobs history and if the server is shutdown it needs to resume any jobs that were previously queued which is why i thought JMS would be the best option. I may need to be able to remove jobs from the queue (cancel unprocessed job). I will try out your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

you can do it perfectly with Camel. The easiest way for me would be: add a JMS queue, accept calls from A and add them to the queue (route 1). Add a JMS listener with 20 consumers to send tasks to B (route 2) and forward B’s response to A back